# In Inkscape is there an easy way to divide my document into equal sections?

Tags: inkscape

I'd like to import 6 pictures (.gif) into an Inkscape Document, and size them equally and place them, well-aligned, into separate sections of the document. My document is in Landscape mode, and for purposes of this exercise, I'd like to place the 6 pictures into two columns, with 3 rows (i.e., a 3 x 2 "table"). Is there any way to do this easily? The way I would think to approach this is to put in gridlines, and do some math to calculate where each of the gridlines should go, then snap the pictures to the appropriate gridlines. Is there an easier way, so that I can just divide the document and save doing the calculations? Also, aside from "eyeballing" it, is there a way to make sure each of the 6 pictures is "automatically" or easily scaled to equal dimensions? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In Inkscape, the *Object > Transform > Scale* tab has an "apply to each object separately" option which could be used to make all selected objects the same dimensions.

*Object > Arrange* can be used to arrange selected objects in a grid.

Just be aware that Inkscape can't handle animated GIFs if you embed the images, they will become static. Although animated GIFs will work if you instead import them as linked files, and have the GIFs in the same directory as the saved SVG, and view the SVG in a browser.

Comment: Thank you! That worked well! To arrange in grid, I did this through a manual process, iteratively grouping by rows, then arranging and distributing, then iteratively grouping by columns, also arranging and distributing. Just curious if there's a way to arrange in a grid with just a click or two, or is the way I described above the only way?

Comment: For the grid, you could use an actual grid, or guides. There are extensions that allow you to create grid guides automatically. For 0.92: https://github.com/sambody/inkscape-guide-tools, for 1.0(beta): https://gitlab.com/Moini/inkscape-guide-tools/ .